# Cannot bitwise on uint and int

Tags: c#, casting, bit-manipulation

So i am confused on why i am getting this error.

```
Operator '<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'uint'
```

Everything is a uint type but it won't accept it.

This is the algorithm:

```
    public void Test(uint[] arr, uint b)
    {
        for (uint x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
        {
            uint reverse = 0;
            for (uint i = 0; i < bits; i++)
            {
                reverse |= (((x & (1 << i)) >> i) & 1) << (b - 1 - i);
            }
            arr[x] = reverse;
        }
    }
```

Why is this not allowed, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side of the operator needs to be an int, as seen in the C# specs

[Standard ECMA-334 - 12.10 Shift operators](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)

> ...
>
> When declaring an overloaded shift operator, the type of the first
>   operand shall always be the class or struct containing the operator
>   declaration, **and the type of the second operand shall always be int**

Probably easiest to use `int`, then convert it to `uint` at the end

```
for (var x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
{
   var reverse = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < bits; i++)
   {
      reverse |= (((x & (1 << i)) >> i) & 1) << ((int)b - 1 - i);
   }

   arr[x] = (uint)reverse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah i opted for that in the end. Don't understand why its not supported for uint though. Its just binary after all...